# Is the set of indistinguishable points measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let X be an uncountable set.

Let S be a countable set of uncountable subsets of X (i.e. there are countably many elements s in S, and each element s in S is an uncountable subset of X). Let R(S) be the sigma-algebra generated by S.

Let x and y be elements of X. We say that x is "indistinguishable from y" if any set s in S contains either both x and y or neither x nor y. A point x in X is "indistinguishable" if there exists some y in X from which it is indistinguishable. Let T be the subset of X which contains all indistinguishable points. (Note that some elements of T can be distinguishable *from each other*).

Claim 1: T is an element of R(S).

Is Claim 1 true? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No.

In this answer the $S$ in your question is denoted as $\mathcal S$.

Let $X$ be an uncountable set and let $A\subseteq X$ be countable and containing at least two elements.

Let $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ such that $B\in\mathcal S$ iff $B$ is countable with $B\cap A=\varnothing$ or $B^{\complement}$ is countable with $B^{\complement}\cap A=\varnothing$.

Then $\mathcal S$ **is** a $\sigma$-algebra, hence coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal S$.

This with $A\notin\mathcal S$ while $A$ is exactly the set of indistinguishable elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the example that I have in mind, the set of indistinguishable elements and the elements of S are uncountable. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: IMV in this context it is not okay to wipe out the original question. Just let it stand and **add** an update by means of an edit. This to avoid that my answer is suddenly degraded to something that "does not answer" the question.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that (it's the first time I'm using this site).